# submit PDF file with formData in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, form-data

I am having problems with formData to submit a pdf file

```
const [file,setFile] = useState()
const [isFilePicked, setIsFilePicked] = useState(false);
```

having an input type file

```
<input  accept=".pdf" type="file" onChange={uploadFile}/>
```

and then the onChange function

```
    const uploadImage = async (e) =>{
  console.log(e.target.files[0])
  setFile(e.target.files[0])
  e.target.files[0] && setIsFilePicked(true);
  }
```

At the end when I want to submit I got "**FormData{}**"

```
const post = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('File',file);
    console.log(formData)
}
```

why am I getting this???

Comment: usestate is asynchronous.What i can guess is that it takes time to set the file. try to call post in settimeout.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If it is, please post an answer

Answer (score 1):

The [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) interface doesn't store the appended key value pairs directly into itself so logging the FormData itself won't output anything. Don't worry, the files are "stored" in the FormData nonetheless. To get the `console.log()` to log the files for you, you have to get the files out of the FormData first. One way is to get the iterator of FormData and then transforming it into object. Example:

```
Object.fromEntries(formData.entries()) // will result in { "File": <your file> }
```

so in case of your code snippet you can do as follows:

```
const post = async () => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('File',file);
  console.log(Object.fromEntries(formData.entries()))
}
```